# Excel keep adding to total

Tags: excel, list, sum, addition

Hi I have been looking for 2 days and I cannot figure this out. I looked online everywhere, this little question is not answered anywhere. I have two drop down lists. One list for question and one for answers, when a question is selected the user then chooses an answer. If it it 'Always' its 1 mark and if its 'Sometimes' its 0.5 mark. I have a current set up in a different row ( on the far right) in many cells if the question is either of the two answers it gets the value 0.5 or 1. The only problem is when the user uses the drop down list to select the next question the if statement is now false and the value goes back to 0 instead of saving. I would like it to save the value after the value is higher then 1 or is there a better way to keep totaling up these answers and still keep my two drop down lists that work together?

Thank you for taking the time to review my question and can't wait to learn how to do this, it has been driving me nuts.
[image]

Comment: Are you answer the same question with the same combobox? linked to the same cell? VBA would be required to make it work corectly

Comment: I don't quite follow. The green 'Are you determined to achieve your goal' is a list of questions. The blue 'Always' is the list of answer. So since the question and answer is up for first question you see a one mark on the top right. Then when clicking the question and choosing a different one the 1 in the top right now becomes a 0 again. So I cant add up the score. Which is my hole problem. Thanks for viewing my question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a practice round for you, once you get it working, you will be able to get it to work for your sheet.

Question DropDown is B10 and Answer is D10

[image: Worksheet Set Up]

Set up the Worksheet.

[image: Data Validation and Results]

[image: Questions]
[image: Answer]

Adding some code.

[image: Right Click sheet Tab]

You are now in the Worksheet Module

[image: Worksheet_Change]

Copy and Paste this code there.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, x As Range, y
    Set rng = Range("G3:G9")

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$D$10" Then
        y = IIf(Target = "Answer 1", 1, 2)
        Set x = rng.Find(what:=Target.Offset(, -2), lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not x Is Nothing Then
            x.Offset(, 1) = y
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$B$10" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = 0
        Target.Offset(, 2).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Close the VBA Editor and work on your the spreadsheet.

[image: Results From Questions]

Formula Counts the results

[image: Formula]

[Example Sheet](http://www.davesexcel.com/lightlyB.xlsm)

Comment: Alright I will try this and let you know. Thanks